# Listing packages installed outside of official repo

Tags: apt, bash, package-management, software-installation, apt-cache

I want to list all the packages in my computer which are not listed in the [official ubuntu repo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/).  I needed a script which is fast enough to do the same thing in under a minute.

Answer (score 3):

This is the code; To make the search faster first I saved the whole available package list in a text file and then did a `grep` on it.

```
# find_foreign_packages.sh
apt-cache search .| grep -o '^[^ - ]*' > pkg_lst.txt

for i in $(apt list --installed| grep -o '^[^/]*'); 
    do 
    output=$(grep -Fx $i pkg_lst.txt)
    if [ -z "$output" ]; then
        echo "$i DOES NOT exists"
    fi
    done;
```